# Tensorflow 2 gradient gives nan results for pow

Tags: python, tensorflow, pow

The following simplified code outputs nan for derivatives when x=0. I'm running tensorflow 2.0.0.

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.Variable([[-1.0], [0.0], [1.0]])

with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as t:
    t.watch(x)
    # case 1: y = x^4
    # y = tf.reduce_sum(tf.pow(x, 4), axis=1) # gives nan for 2nd to 5th derivative at x=0
    # case 2: y = x + x^2 + x^3 + x^4
    y = tf.reduce_sum(tf.pow(x, [[1, 2, 3, 4]]), axis=1) # gives nan for 2nd to 5th derivative at x=0
    dy_dx = t.gradient(y, x)
    d2y_dx2 = t.gradient(dy_dx, x)
    d3y_dx3 = t.gradient(d2y_dx2, x)
    d4y_dx4 = t.gradient(d3y_dx3, x)
    d5y_dx5 = t.gradient(d4y_dx4, x)
del t

tf.print(y)
tf.print(tf.transpose(dy_dx)) # transpose only to fit on one line when printed
tf.print(tf.transpose(d2y_dx2))
tf.print(tf.transpose(d3y_dx3))
tf.print(tf.transpose(d4y_dx4))
tf.print(tf.transpose(d5y_dx5))
```

This outputs correct values except when x=0:

```
[0 0 4]
[[-2 1 10]]
[[8 -nan(ind) 20]]
[[-18 -nan(ind) 30]]
[[24 -nan(ind) 24]]
[[0 -nan(ind) 0]]
```

If you run the `tf.pow(x, 4)` case instead, the nan only shows up for the 5th derivative:

```
[1 0 1]
[[-4 0 4]]
[[12 0 12]]
[[-24 0 24]]
[[24 24 24]]
[[-0 -nan(ind) 0]]
```

So my questions are:

- The tensorflow documentation doesn't explicitly say that the pow function supports two parameters of different size, but the first output y is correct. Anyone have experience with this? I'm expecting a matrix of all 3 input `x` values raised to all 4 powers.
- Is the nan value returned from the gradient a bug I should report? I did find this previous possibly related issue, but it was fixed: https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/issues/346